# User Guessing System for Sports - SQL Issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a sports system in PHP/MySQL. With some help on StackOverFlow, I have built it.

I have OW_SPORTS_GAMES table which has all details about each games played with team Id and scores. Here is the structure.

[image]

Also there is another table OW_SPORTS_PREDICTIONS where user predictions about games results are stored. User can predict which team will be winning the game. Here is the table structure.

[image]

I am looking to get the result where I can know how many correct and wrong predictions each user has made. If it's a correct guess, user is awarded the points present for each game (points column). The output should ignore any games where scores of both team is 0.

Here is my current SQL:

```
SELECT p.userId,
       SUM(IF(g.id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) correct,
       SUM(IF(g.id IS NULL, 1, 0)) wrong,
       SUM(IF(g.id IS NOT NULL, g.points, 0)) AS points
  FROM
       (SELECT * FROM ow_sports_games WHERE seasonId = 10 AND (homeTeamScore > 0 OR awayTeamScore > 0) ) g
  RIGHT JOIN ow_sports_predictions p
     ON g.id = p.gameId
    AND p.teamId = IF(g.homeTeamScore > g.awayTeamScore , g.homeTeam, IF(g.homeTeamScore < g.awayTeamScore , g.awayTeam, NULL))
  GROUP BY p.userId ORDER BY points DESC, correct DESC, wrong DESC;
```

With this SQL I am getting wrong stats where games not predicted by user and scores 0-0 are also considered.

**SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4c9ed/2**

In the same fiddle data, it should be 2 correct and 2 wrong predictions. But it comes as 2 correct and 4 wrong predictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are limiting the JOIN to only return games where the prediction is correct;

```
AND p.teamId = IF(g.homeTeamScore > g.awayTeamScore , g.homeTeam, IF(g.homeTeamScore < g.awayTeamScore , g.awayTeam, NULL))
```

However, your assumption when calculating the number of wrong predictions is that the game id will be null:

```
SUM(IF(g.id IS NULL, 1, 0)) wrong,
```

However, the game id will also be null if the score is `0-0` which you are trying to exlude. I would simplify this, first by making the join criteria simple, so you can switch to an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ow_sports_predictions p
        INNER JOIN ow_sports_games g
            ON g.id = p.gameId
WHERE   g.SeasonID = 10
```

Then you can determine your logic for if the prediction was correct (this is more verbose than I will use later but demonstrates the logic better),

```
SELECT  *,
        CASE WHEN g.homeTeamScore > g.awayTeamScore AND g.HomeTeam = p.TeamID THEN 'Correct - Home Win'
            WHEN g.awayTeamScore > g.homeTeamScore AND g.AwayTeam = p.Teamid THEN 'Correct - Away Win'
            WHEN g.homeTeamScore + g.awayTeamScore = 0 THEN 'Void (0-0)'
            ELSE 'Lose'
        END AS Result
FROM    ow_sports_predictions p
        INNER JOIN ow_sports_games g
            ON g.id = p.gameId
WHERE   g.SeasonID = 10;
```

Finally, we can sum it all up:

```
SELECT  p.userID,
        SUM(IF((g.homeTeamScore > g.awayTeamScore AND g.HomeTeam = p.TeamID) 
            OR (g.awayTeamScore > g.homeTeamScore AND g.AwayTeam = p.TeamID), 1, 0)) AS Correct,
        SUM(IF((g.homeTeamScore < g.awayTeamScore AND g.HomeTeam = p.TeamID) 
            OR (g.awayTeamScore < g.homeTeamScore AND g.AwayTeam = p.TeamID), 1, 0)) AS Wrong,
        SUM(IF((g.homeTeamScore > g.awayTeamScore AND g.HomeTeam = p.TeamID) 
            OR (g.awayTeamScore > g.homeTeamScore AND g.AwayTeam = p.TeamID), g.Points, 0)) AS Points,
        COUNT(*) AS TotalPredictions
FROM    ow_sports_predictions p
        INNER JOIN ow_sports_games g
            ON g.id = p.gameId
WHERE   g.SeasonID = 10
GROUP BY p.UserID;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4c9ed/47)**

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I am not sure how you guys have such a brain :) Looks like you solved my problem.

Comment: Just to add further explanation. This could be made to look a lot simpler by moving logic to subqueries, unfortunately looking simpler to the human eye, and looking simpler to the MySQL db engine are two different things, and when it encounters a subquery MySQL essentially dumps the entire subquery into a temporary table and then references that, meaning you lose performance. This is why I have tried to avoid subqueries by repeating what is essentially the same logic and keeping primary table references rather than derived.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main root of your problem is use of RIGHT join when joining in the predictions -- this will give you rows of data for games that you did not want to count... Try changing that to a LEFT join and let us know.

**Update:** Ouch down-voted for pointing out that the RIGHT join was pulling in extra records?  There were other issues, but I think that was the biggest.  Since obviously I am supposed to provide a complete answer, here is a query that I would use, with accompanying fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4c9ed/49

```
SELECT s.userId,
  SUM(IF(s.teamId = s.winningTeam, 1, 0)) correct,
  SUM(IF(s.teamId != s.winningTeam, 0, 1)) wrong,
  SUM(IF(s.teamId = s.winningTeam, s.points, 0)) points
FROM
  (SELECT p.*, g.points,
   IF (g.homeTeamScore-g.awayTeamScore > 0, g.homeTeam, g.awayTeam) as winningTeam
   FROM ow_sports_predictions p
    INNER JOIN ow_sports_games g ON g.id = p.gameId AND g.homeTeamScore+g.awayTeamScore > 0) s
GROUP BY s.userId;
```

Comment: Sorry, it was me that down-voted but didn't have time to write a proper explanation as to why, so didn't put an explanation at all (right or wrong of me). The fact that it was a `RIGHT` join was not the issue, it was the join conditions, and simply changing the JOIN to a `LEFT JOIN` would not have solved this. Anyway, you have since provided a better answer, and I have subsequently removed the down-vote.

Answer (score 1):

Here is mine, which gives you your answer.

```
select sp.userid,
       sum(if ( (sp.teamid = sg.idwinner), 1, 0 )) correct,
       sum(if ( (sp.teamid != sg.idwinner), 0, 1)) wrong,
       sum(if ( (sp.teamid = sg.idwinner), sg.points, 0 )) points
  from (select if ( homeTeamScore>awayTeamScore, homeTeam, awayTeam ) idwinner,
               sg.* 
         from ow_sports_games sg
        where homeTeamScore>0 and awayTeamScore>0 ) sg,
       ow_sports_predictions sp
 where sg.id = sp.gameid
 group by sp.userid
```

[Fiddle with your data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53217/1) with some of the points changed.

Comment: Thats ok when I submitted I saw that you already have choosed. My mistake for not hit on F5 :)

Answer (score 0):

here is quick variant, it calculates all numbers for each user, of course you need only 2 of them, it is enough to calculate 3rd:

```
select
  b.userId,
  count(*) as total_predictions,
  sum(if(b.teamId=q.winteam,1,0)) as correct_predictions,
  sum(if(b.teamId<>q.winteam,1,0)) as wrong_predictions
from ow_sports_predictions as b
inner join
(
select
a.id,
if (a.hometeamscore>a.awayteamscore, a.hometeam, if(a.hometeamscore<a.awayteamscore, a.awayteam, -1)) as winteam
from ow_sports_games as a
)
as q
on (b.gameId=q.id)
group by b.userId;
```

and here is simplified version:

```
select
  b.userId,
  count(*) as total_predictions,
  sum(if(b.teamId=if (q.hometeamscore>q.awayteamscore, q.hometeam, if(q.hometeamscore<q.awayteamscore, q.awayteam, -1)),1,0)) as correct_predictions
from ow_sports_predictions as b
inner join ow_sports_games as q
on (b.gameId=q.id)
group by b.userId;
```

to calculate points, you need to change `1` in `IF` to `points`, like:

```
select
  b.userId,
  count(*) as total_predictions,
  sum(if(b.teamId=if (q.hometeamscore>q.awayteamscore, q.hometeam, if(q.hometeamscore<q.awayteamscore, q.awayteam, -1)),q.points,0)) as correct_predictions_mul_points
from ow_sports_predictions as b
inner join ow_sports_games as q
on (b.gameId=q.id)
group by b.userId;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But your SQL is taking even the games for which the scores are 0-0. I am sure you might know the best way to handle this too.

Comment: @Purus check sql again, even if it takes 0-0 - it calculates right